# Entrada de dados - Java

Tags: java, entrada-de-dados

Na hora da entrada de dados, percebi que quando eu coloco o nome do produto e dou enter, sempre fica uma linha solta, a próxima pergunta não vem na hora, só depois de outro enter. No entanto, quando coloco o nome do produto, dou espaço e depois enter, a próxima instrução chega na hora. Pq isso acontece?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int count = 0, qtd, precoInferior = 0, qtdProdutoEntre = 0, qtdProSuperior = 0;
Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Digite a quantidade de produtos: ");
qtd = In.nextInt();
In.nextLine();
float preco[] = new float[qtd];
float somaDosPro = 0, mediaDosPro;
String nome[] = new String[qtd];
String nomeProdutoEntre[] = new String[qtd];

for(int i = 0; i < qtd; i++)
{ 
 System.out.printf("\nDigite o nome do %d° produto:\n", (count + 1));
 nome[count] = In.nextLine();
 System.out.printf("Digite o preço do %d° produto:\n", (count + 1));
  preco[count] = In.nextFloat();
 In.nextLine();
  if(preco[count] < 40)
  {precoInferior++;}
 if(preco[count] >= 40 && preco[count] <= 100)
  { 
  nomeProdutoEntre[qtdProdutoEntre] = nome[count];
  qtdProdutoEntre++;
  }
 if(preco[count] > 100)
 {
  qtdProSuperior++;
  somaDosPro = preco[count] + somaDosPro;  
 }
 count++;
}
System.out.printf("\na) Há %d produto(s) com preço inferior a 40,00 R$.", precoInferior);
System.out.println("\nb) Produto(s) com preço entre 40,00 R$ e 100,00 R$: ");
if(qtdProdutoEntre == 0)
{System.out.println("Inexistentes.");}
else{
for(int j = 0; j < qtdProdutoEntre; j++)
{ System.out.println(nomeProdutoEntre[j]);
}
 }
 mediaDosPro = somaDosPro/qtdProSuperior;
 if(qtdProSuperior == 0)
 {
   System.out.println("c)Não há produtos com preço superior a 100,00 R$.");
 }
 else
{
 System.out.printf("c)Média: %.2f R$.", mediaDosPro);
}
In.close();
  }

}
```

Comment: É uma das propriedades do nextLine, tenta ao invés de usar nextLine usar o next()

Answer (score -2):

Utilize o `BufferedReader In = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));` em vez do `Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);`
É preciso substituir todas as chamadas In para `In.readLine()`, em caso de inteiros utilize
`Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());` em caso de Double `Double.parseDouble(entrada.readLine());`em caso de Float `Float.parseFloat(entrada.readLine());`